# Glassfish sun-ejb-jar.xml DTD deploy error

Tags: java, deployment, glassfish, ejb, dtd

I try to deploy era archive in Glassfish, with very simple sun-ej-jar file with DTD string:

```
<!DOCTYPE sun-ejb-jar PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Application Server 9.1.1 EJB 3.0//EN" "http://www.sun.com/software/appserver/dtds/sun-ejb-jar_3_0-1.dtd">
```

I I get an error:

```
“Error occurred during deployment: Exception while deploying the app [app]: Unable to locate the DTD to validate your deployment descriptor file [META-INF/sun-ejb-jar.xml] in archive [app-ejb-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT_jar]. Please make sure the DOCTYPE is correct (no type in public ID or system Id) and you have proper access to the internet.. Please see sever.log for more details.”
```

**Notes:**

1. Computer with glassfish does not have access to Internet.
2. I put sun-ejb-jar_3_0-1.dtd in glassfish\lib\dtds folder.
3. DTD string exactly the same as in sun-ejb-jar_3_0-1.dtd (line 49).
4. If I "Application Server 9.1.1" replace with "Application Server 9.0" the application eploys **without any error**!

I use glassfish 3.1.2

Does someone know the problem?

P.S. server.log contains stack trace with DTD validation error, no something useful.